# The levers puzzle

Tags: go

I started playing [Pathfinder: Kingmaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinder:_Kingmaker), and very soon ended up in a room with 6 levers, and a task to open a secret door by manipulating the levers. I assumed that the correct position for all the levers is up. But when you flip a single lever, one or two other levers also flip. For example, if you flip lever one, then levers two and four also flip, when you flip lever two, lever one also flips, etc.

But you know what, programming is more fun than playing games, so let's figure out what levers we need to pull in what sequence to get all of them up!

Feedback sought: I'm novice in golang, anything goes!

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type node struct {
    state      int         // a bitmask for every possible levers' configuration, lever one is the least significant bit, 1 is up, 0 is down
    neighbours []int       // all configurations (states, above) that are reachable by flipping a single lever
    levers     map[int]int // lookup that given a neighbour state gives what lever is pulled to reach this state
}

// given levers configuration, print it out in human-readable format
func formatState(state int, width int) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < width; i++ {
        var desc string
        if state&1 == 0 {
            desc = "down"
        } else {
            desc = "up"
        }
        state >>= 1
        sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d - %s; ", i+1, desc))
    }
    result := sb.String()
    if len(result) > 2 { // remove final "; "
        result = result[:len(result)-2]
    }
    return result
}

func printSolution(graph []node, prev map[int]int, start, end, width int) {
    path := []int{end}
    for z := end; z != start; z = prev[z] {
        path = append(path, prev[z])
    }
    for i, j := 0, len(path)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        path[i], path[j] = path[j], path[i]
    }
    for i := 1; i < len(path); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Pull lever %d:\n", graph[path[i-1]].levers[path[i]]+1)
        fmt.Println(formatState(path[i], width))
    }
}

// Simplified Dijkstra's algorithm
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode
func search(graph []node, start, end int) map[int]int {
    q := []int{start}
    prev := map[int]int{}
    dist := map[int]int{}
    for len(q) > 0 {
        u := q[0]
        q = q[1:]
        if u == end {
            return prev
        }
        for _, v := range graph[u].neighbours {
            alt := dist[u] + 1
            if i, ok := dist[v]; !ok || alt < i {
                prev[v] = u
                dist[v] = alt
                q = append(q, v)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func initGraph(levers []int) []node {
    var graph = make([]node, 1<<len(levers))
    for i := 0; i < len(graph); i++ {
        graph[i].state = i
        graph[i].levers = make(map[int]int)
        for j := 0; j < len(levers); j++ {
            n := i ^ levers[j]
            graph[i].neighbours = append(graph[i].neighbours, n)
            graph[i].levers[n] = j
        }
    }
    return graph
}

func main() {
    // This can come from an external input, but let's not overcomplicate:
    var levers = []int{
        0b001011, // lever one flips levers one, two and four
        0b000011, // lever two flips levers one, and two
        0b100100, // lever three flips levers three, two and six
        0b011001, // lever four flips levers one, four and five
        0b111000, // lever five flips levers four, five and six
        0b110100, // lever six flips levers three, five and six
    }
    width := len(levers)
    graph := initGraph(levers)
    start := 0b011111
    end := 0b111111
    fmt.Printf("Starting poisition:\n%s\n", formatState(start, width))
    fmt.Printf("Goal poisition:\n%s\n", formatState(end, width))
    prev := search(graph, start, end)
    if prev != nil {
        printSolution(graph, prev, start, end, width)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Solution not found")
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Starting poisition:
1 - up; 2 - up; 3 - up; 4 - up; 5 - up; 6 - down
Goal poisition:
1 - up; 2 - up; 3 - up; 4 - up; 5 - up; 6 - up
Pull lever 1:
1 - down; 2 - down; 3 - up; 4 - down; 5 - up; 6 - down
Pull lever 2:
1 - up; 2 - up; 3 - up; 4 - down; 5 - up; 6 - down
Pull lever 3:
1 - up; 2 - up; 3 - down; 4 - down; 5 - up; 6 - up
Pull lever 5:
1 - up; 2 - up; 3 - down; 4 - up; 5 - down; 6 - down
Pull lever 6:
1 - up; 2 - up; 3 - up; 4 - up; 5 - up; 6 - up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to explicitly initialize the graph. It is waste of time and space. The graph has a very regular and predictable structure, so the neighbors could be computed on the fly during traversal.
- `map` is a heavyweight structure, and looks like an overkill (again, the graph is *very* regular). A simple `[] int`, indexed by `state` seems to suffice both for `prev` and `dist`.
- A single-letter identifiers (`i, u, v` in `search`) are kind of hard to follow. `ok` and `alt` are not of a great help either.
- States in the output table are misaligned. Consider changing the description to `"  up"` (or something else of the same length as `"down"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
prev := map[int]int{}
```

It's possibly more idiomatic to use var and make rather than the shorthand declaration for an empty map? You would usually use the shorthand declaration to assign an initial value, and var to initialise to the zero value.

You are doing so in initGraph. Might be good to keep this consistent throughout your code.